# how to display tag/images on camera/surface in android

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

Here I am creating a application that uses camera and surface.

In that application I am using maps also when I will start application it should be display some tags on that camera surface which is around me.

I have some snapshot regarding app which we need to do.

[image]

in that only button is there but i want dynamic tags like maps.

I want like this image is below....
In this snap that tags is generated dynamic as per maps' tags

[image]

Sorry for my English and Grammer.
Thanks

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted, if it's ok for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use relativelayout. Put your surface and tags (image buttons or others) into this.

Comment: Here is some example on how to use relative layouts:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html